# How can I return an immovable object from a C++ coroutine?

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++-coroutine

As of C++17, normal functions can return non-movable non-copyable values. Silly example:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> silly() {
  return std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(my_mutex);
}
```

What must I put in a coroutine and its promise type to do the same with `co_return`?

```
???? co_silly() {
    co_return std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(my_mutex);
}
```

Comment: Coroutines are a clumsy cludge, in C++, and they don't integrate well with the rest of the language, so nobody should be surprised to learn that they, well, don't integrate with the rest of the language.

Comment: I think it is not possible. The return value of a coroutine needs two distinct steps; get result into the promise (during `promise.return_value()`) then get coroutine result from the promise. If the object is not movable that cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, in general it is not possible.
You would need to store/copy it inside `promise_type` to have access to it from the coroutine client code. And it cannot be done, because, well, the type cannot be copied/moved to.

But it is possible to just keep in `promise_type` the pointer to local(automatic) variable from the coroutine body. Additionaly it cannot be done with `co_return`. It is only possible with `co_yield`.

```
struct coro {
   std::coroutine_type<promise_type> handle;
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex>& get_lock() { return *handle.promise().lock; }
   
   ...
   struct promise_type {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>* lock;
        void return_void() {}
        auto yield_value(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>&& l) {
           lock = &l;
           return std::suspend_always{};
        }
        std::suspend_always() final_suspend() noexcept;
        ...
   };
};

coro silly_coro() {
   co_yield std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m);
}
```

**Details below:**

**Why you cannot use `co_return` to keep pointer to local variables from coroutine:**

You can store in `promise type` the pointer to immovable variable, as long as you can be sure the local(automatic) variable inside coroutine body outlives the usage of it.

And this is tricky - because you cannot use the `co_return` - because `co_return` means you are suspending coroutine in `final_suspend` - which means all local(automatic) variable are already destructed as pretty well described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211013-00/?p=105797). In short - coroutine body is inside try-block which means every locals got destroyed before final suspend:

```
// pseudo-code for coroutine
promise = ...;
promise.initial_suspend();
try { coroutine_body; }
catch(...) { promise.unhandle_exception(); }
promise.final_suspend(); // !!!
```

So this code is not possible, the `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m)` is destructed before `final_suspend`.

```
struct coro {
   std::coroutine_type<promise_type> handle;
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex>& get_lock() { return *handle.promise().lock; }
   
   ...
   struct promise_type {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>* lock;
        void return_value(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>&& l) {
           lock = &l;
        }
        std::suspend_always() final_suspend() noexcept;
        ...
   };
};

coro silly_coro() {
   co_return std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m);
}

int main() {
   auto c = silly_coro();
   auto& lock = c.get_lock(); // lock is already destructed here!
```

**Why it is possible with `co_await`:**

You can just use `co_yield` instead of `co_return` - and until you resume the coroutine manually - the reference to local unmovable variable from inside coroutine will be available to use.

```
struct coro {
   std::coroutine_type<promise_type> handle;
   std::lock_guard<std::mutex>& get_lock() { return *handle.promise().lock; }
   
   ...
   struct promise_type {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex>* lock;
        void return_void() {}
        auto yield_value(std::lock_guard<std::mutex>&& l) {
           lock = &l;
           return std::suspend_always{};
        }
        std::suspend_always() final_suspend() noexcept;
        ...
   };
};

coro silly_coro() {
   co_yield std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(m);
}

int main() {
   auto c = silly_coro();
   auto& lock = c.get_lock(); // lock is still alive
   // until the point of resuming coroutine on avaitable created by co_yield
   c.handle.resume(); // now lock is destructed
```

Full [example](https://godbolt.org/z/7revovPT9) with some extra debug proving it works.